# Regex to get text between multiple newlines in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split a text where it is between \n\n and \n, in that order. Take this string for example:

`\n\nMy take on fruits.\n\nHealthy Fruits\nAn apple is a fruit and it\'s very good.\n\nPears are good as well. Bananas are very good too and healthy.\n\nSour Fruits\nOranges are on the sour side and contains a lot of vitamin C.\n\nGrapefruits are even more sour, if you can believe it.`

My desired output is:

`[('Healthy Fruits',   "An apple is a fruit and it's very good.", 'Pears are good as well. Bananas are very good too and healthy.'),  ('Sour Fruits',   'Oranges are on the sour side and contains a lot of vitamin C.', 'Grapefruits are even more sour, if you can believe it.')]`

I want to parse like this because anything between \n\n and \n is the title and the rest is text under the title (So "Healthy Fruits" and "Sour Fruits" . Not sure if this is the best way to grab the titles and its text.

Comment: `re.split(r'\n\n?, ur_txt)`

Comment: Maybe `re.findall('(?<!\n)\n\n(.+)\n(?!\n)((?s:.*?))(?=\n\n|\Z)', text)`  will do.

Comment: @dawg  Thanks, I edited my question.  I wanted to group the last sentence with Grapefruits with the Oranges sentence as they are part of the same title.  Would this be possible?

Comment: Why with Regex? I can would use another way, and btw why do you expect the last one?"Grapefruits are even more sour, if you can believe it."?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, I edited my question.  I wanted to group the last sentence with Grapefruits with the Oranges sentence as they are part of the same title.  Would this be possible?  Right now it just takes the Oranges sentence instead of combining Oranges and Grapefruits sentences together into one string. I would like: ```[('Healthy Fruits',
  "An apple is a fruit and it's very good. Bananas are very good too and healthy."),
 ('Sour Fruits',
  'Oranges are on the sour side and contains a lot of vitamin C.', 
 'Grapefruits are even more sour, if you can believe it.')]```

Comment: You can't do that, it is against the described logic. `\n\n` separates a new title.

Comment: @NirElbaz  I would expect the Grapefruits sentence to be combined with the Oranges sentence.  My objective is to parse a long text with many paragraphs and titles and put the formatted text (titles with their relevant paragraphs) into a PDF.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Or would this be possible?
```[('Healthy Fruits',   "An apple is a fruit and it's very good. Bananas are very good too and healthy."),  ('Sour Fruits',   'Oranges are on the sour side and contains a lot of vitamin C. Grapefruits are even more sour, if you can believe it.')]```

Comment: @user112947 so you want to add the last sentence no matter if it doesnt fit the rule?

Comment: Only something like `[(x,y.replace('\n\n', ' ')) for x,y in re.findall('(?<!\n)\n\n(.+)\n(?!\n)((?s:.*?)(?:\n\n.+$)?)(?=\n\n|$)', text)]`

Comment: @NirElbaz Correct.  But it could also be like this too where such \n\n sentence could be in the middle of the string.
```\n\nMy take on fruits.\n\nHealthy Fruits\nAn apple is a fruit and it\'s very good.\n\nPears are good as well. Bananas are very good too and healthy.\n\nSour Fruits\nOranges are on the sour side and contains a lot of vitamin C.\n\nGrapefruits are even more sour, if you can believe it.```

Comment: Then how do you describe a title? What is its pattern? You can't rely on the number of `\n` here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Apologies for the confusion.  A title is always between \n\n and \n. If there is a \n\n in front of text that is not followed by \n (so not a title), then it is a new paragraph so it should be a separate string. My desired output would be:
```[('Healthy Fruits',   "An apple is a fruit and it's very good.", 'Pears are good as well. Bananas are very good too and healthy.'),  ('Sour Fruits',   'Oranges are on the sour side and contains a lot of vitamin C.', 'Grapefruits are even more sour, if you can believe it.')]```

Comment: Is `\n\nMy take on fruits.\n\n` just discarded?

Comment: @dawg If the title isn't at the start of the string, then yes, the leading text until the first title can be discarded, but doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
txt='''\
\n\nMy take on fruits.\n\nHealthy Fruits\nAn apple is a fruit and it\'s very good.\n\nPears are good as well. Bananas are very good too and healthy.\n\nSour Fruits\nOranges are on the sour side and contains a lot of vitamin C.\n\nGrapefruits are even more sour, if you can believe it.'''

desired=[('Healthy Fruits',   "An apple is a fruit and it's very good.", 'Pears are good as well. Bananas are very good too and healthy.'),  ('Sour Fruits',   'Oranges are on the sour side and contains a lot of vitamin C.', 'Grapefruits are even more sour, if you can believe it.')]
```

You can use the regex:

```
r'\n\n([\s\S]*?)(?=(?:\n\n.*\n[^\n])|\Z)'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WKdYPY/1/)

Python demo:

```
>>> sp=[tuple(re.split('\n+',l)) for l in re.findall(r'\n\n([\s\S]*?)(?=(?:\n\n.*\n[^\n])|\Z)',txt) if '\n' in l]

>>> sp
[('Healthy Fruits', "An apple is a fruit and it's very good.", 'Pears are good as well. Bananas are very good too and healthy.'), ('Sour Fruits', 'Oranges are on the sour side and contains a lot of vitamin C.', 'Grapefruits are even more sour, if you can believe it.')]

>>> sp==desired
True
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This not regex  but it works:

```
text="\n\nMy take on fruits.\n\nHealthy Fruits\nAn apple is a fruit and it\'s very good. Bananas are very good too and healthy.\n\nSour Fruits\nOranges are on the sour side and contains a lot of vitamin C.\n\nGrapefruits are even more sour, if you can believe it."
    NewList=[]
    Newtext=text.split("\n\n")
    for line in Newtext:
        if line.find("\n")>=0:
            NewList.extend(line.split('\n'))
    
    NewList[len(NewList)-1]=str(NewList[len(NewList)-1])+str(Newtext[len(Newtext)-1])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!